# websocket on Saucelabs immediately drops connection (code 1006)

Tags: angularjs, websocket, saucelabs

I am trying to run some simple tests for an app that runs websockets . The wesocket connection is abruptly stopped and tests fail.
The tests are not related to websockets at all . They are about a click on a button on the page which appears only after some data is received over websockets. I have attached the screenshot from a manual session.
[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing and filed a ticket with Sauce Labs support. I will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Hello, has the ticket been resolved?

Comment: No. I guess Sauce Connect currently doesn't support WebSockets. They are going to update me when they add it.

Answer (score 1):

To this date it is not supported directly (SauceLabs is using Squid as a proxy server for their Connect Plugin which introduced this limitation on their end).

However, if you still want to use Sauce Connect - you can work around this problem quite easily by applying a workaround that [I blogged about here](http://orcaman.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/working-around-ssh-tunnel-limitations.html).

The basic idea is this:

1. Have one empty page hosted on a publicly accessible URL (for example: qa.yoursite.com/test-container.html). This page contains nothing except for a script reference to localhost (something like localhost/injected.js)
2. When you start Sauce Connect (if you are using Travis CI, read my blog entry, there's a comment about that) with the -D flag over your domain:

   bin/sc -D *.yoursite.com
3. Have your machine/CI server host the injected.js file locally. This file can execute WebSockets tests, even though it is fetched the via the SSH tunnel - because it is contained in a non-tunneled page (yoursite.com/test-container.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since orcaman's blog, SauceLabs have added the https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sauce-connect/#Additional-options in their script. You can now specify `direct_domains`, `no_ssl_bump_domains`, and `tunnel_domains` directly from your `.travis.yml`.

I used the following config

```
# https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sauce-connect/
sauce_connect:
  username: "jdanekrh"
  access_key:
    secure: "****"
  no_ssl_bump_domains: "127.0.0.1,localhost"
```

The `no_ssl_bump_domains` is supposed to prevent squid proxy from breaking my WebSockets. It seems to be working for me. = [1], [2]

Source: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Troubleshooting+Sauce+Connect section Disabling SSL Bumping.

1. https://travis-ci.org/jdanekrh/dispatch-console-tests/jobs/224632420
2. https://saucelabs.com/beta/builds/9fd55cc6a33a44bfa3653896d5cfb3dc

Comment: I don't really understand what the option means, though. That the data between SauceLabs and my website will go unencrypted? Probably not, since it is inside a tunnel...